# Unable to import scipy but can import numpy in IronPython

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ironpython

I am trying to port my code from `Python(v2.7)` to `IronPython` so as to be able to leverage the multiple cores I have at my disposal on my lab computers.

I first installed `IronPython` from: http://ironpython.net/

Then I installed (or at least I think I have) the packages `numpy` and `scipy` following the instructions given here: https://www.enthought.com/repo/.iron/
I also tried the last command given on the page (`> ipy -X:Frames -c "import scipy"`) and, since the command prompt didn't spit out an error, I assumed that everything went well.

But strangely enough, I can import `numpy` but I cannot import `scipy`. The following is the error message I get:

```
IronPython 2.7.4 (2.7.0.40) on .NET 4.0.30319.18444 (32-bit)
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.pi
3.141592653589793
>>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.p
y", line 124, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\numpy\_import_to
ols.py", line 15, in __init__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_getframe'
```

What have I missed here? I searched Google for `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_getframe'`, but was not able to find a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use an interactive window? You can add the "-X:Frames" like this

```
1. Go to: Tools -> Options -> Python Tools -> Interactive Windows -> IronPython 2.7

2. Set "Interpreter Options" to "-X:Frames"
```

Also, check if the -X:Frames is on the output when you run this command

```
PS> ( Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "Name like '%ipy%'" ).CommandLine
```

If not, then something goes wrong with "-X:Frames".

Comment: But where can I fine this `Tools>>Options>>Python Tools>>`? Could you tell me a bit more specifically?

Comment: You could use VS for example for the interactive window. Have you tried the second one? Is the "-X:Frames" in the output?

Comment: I don't have visual studio. For CPython I have just been using Notepad++ and the command prompt. About the second one: how to set the Interpreter Options?

Comment: I was talking about the command to see the output. Maybe you don't set up correctly the -x:frames

Comment: Sorry about this, but I am completely lost here. I executed the command `( Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "Name like '%ipy%'" ).CommandLine` in the command prompt. I got the error `.CommandLine was unexpected at this time.` Thanks for your help, but I am not able to understand where to go and to execute the instructions that you have mentioned.